# How can generate RDLC report on two columns?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, rdlc

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I must generate a REPORT like that:

```
 _________________________________
| NAME SURNAME   | NAME SURNAME   |
| ADDRESS        | ADDRESS        |
| NUMBER         | NUMBER         |
|                |                |
| NAME SURNAME   | NAME SURNAME   |
| ADDRESS        | ADDRESS        |
| NUMBER         | NUMBER         |
```

But the result now is like that:

```
 _________________________________
| NAME SURNAME   |                |
| ADDRESS        |                |
| NUMBER         |                |
|                |                |
| NAME SURNAME   |                |
| ADDRESS        |                |
| NUMBER         |                |
|                |                |
| NAME SURNAME   |                |
| ADDRESS        |                |
| NUMBER         |                |
|                |                |
| NAME SURNAME   |                |
| ADDRESS        |                |
| NUMBER         |                |
```

I've associated to my report a DataSource (one Business Object) like that:

```
public class User
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Surname {get;set;}
   etc..
}
```

I've tried with Table, Lists and Matrix but I have had always the second result.

How can I fix that?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 7):

Ciao,

you have to set `Columns` and `ColumnSpacing` properties of your report:

1. display `Property` window
2. click on `Report` (grey area outside your page)
3. find and set `Columns` property

Comment: Very nice! I never used that property and was pondering over this question for couple of days. Glad to learn something new!

Comment: @tezzo Can you tell what to do after generating that column?

Comment: Simply put your table/list/objects in the first column: reporting services automatically fills colums when rendering your data.

Answer (score 0):

I never done this kind of report but think you are after newsletter-Style report.
you can find more information here
[MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159107(SQL.100).aspx) and [example solution](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2012/11/01/creating-multiple-column-reports/)