# Print RDLC report across multiple columns (newspaper format)

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am trying to create an RDLC report in a newspaper like 2 column format. This is my first venture into RDLC report and I am an absolute noob here.

> I have tried to follow the instructions here
>   [How can generate RDLC report on two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343587/how-can-generate-rdlc-report-on-two-columns)

but still my report shows up in one single column. I have decreased my font so that there is plenty of space for both columns to fit, but still the report body content never spills over to the second column

Some other forums tell to use a filter variable to display odd rows on the left and even rows on the right, and so on, but I cannot use that approach because the client requirement is that the second column will only be used if the first column is filled.

> I am attaching a screenshot of my first version RDLC design.

[image]

> I am also attaching a screenshot of the report format that is actually required see bellow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have this wast "white space" around your table which still counts for "used" space. This could be one of the things that makes RDLC "push" what is can to the second page. The things to do is to:

1. Reduce report size (in designer) to the table size with no white space
2. Set report size and margins in Report Properties window:

[image]

3. Look at Columns and ColumnSpacing properties of your report as per: 
   [.rdlc report: text on page in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791307/rdlc-report-text-on-page-in-two-columns)